# How to read JSON and redirect a download

Tags: javascript, html, json, github-api

I am trying to make it so my website reads [githubs api](https://api.github.com/repos/portablemc/portablemc/releases/latest) and automatically sends the user to the latest download link, In this case the tag is `browser_download_url`, How would I go about using `JSON.parse()` or something else to read this and redirect the user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be no need to call `JSON.stringify` if you use the `fetch` API.

You can destructure the URL from the JSON object and then open a new tab for that URL to initiate a download.

```js
fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/portablemc/portablemc/releases/latest')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    const { assets: [ { browser_download_url } ] } = json; // Destructure
    
    console.log(browser_download_url);                     // Log the URL
    
    window.open(browser_download_url, '_blank');           // Open a new tab
  });
```

If you want this to be a button, you could write a function like so:

```js
const main = async () => {
  const btn = await initDownloadButton('#download-btn', {
    url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/portablemc/portablemc/releases/latest'
  });
  console.log(`Initialized: #${btn.id}`);
};

const initDownloadButton = async (btn, options) => {
  if (typeof btn === 'string') btn = document.querySelector(btn);
  const downloadUrl = await fetchLatestDownloadUrl(options.url);
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(`Opening: ${downloadUrl}`);
    window.open(downloadUrl, '_blank')
  });
  return btn;
};

const fetchLatestDownloadUrl = async (url) => {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const { assets: [ { browser_download_url } ] } = await response.json();
  return browser_download_url;
}

main();
```

```html
<button id="download-btn">Download</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I go about connecting it to a HTML button?

Comment: @yeetedmeme I added an `async`/`await` example.